# Passing a descendant instead of an interface in java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I'm implementing two types of list in Java, one that is just a list of labels and other one that also offers two buttons on each row.

I've created an interface called IListView, and it contains the following method:

```
public void setDataSource(IListViewDataSource dataSource);
```

The problem is that when creating the second type of list, which uses another type of data source called `IComplexListViewDataSource` that extends the previous one, and implementing the previous method like this:

```
public void setDataSource(IComplexListViewDataSource dataSource);
```

IntelliJ tells me I'm not overriding the method in the `IListView` interface, even though `IComplexListViewDataSource` extends `IListViewDataSource`.

If I'm correct, this would work without problems if I was dealing with classes instead of interfaces. What's going on and how can I get this to work?

Comment: You cannot make the contract stricter (subclass in place of superclass)

Comment: @user7 I'm not sure what you mean, can't I specify a subtype of `IListViewDataSource` in order to use its methods?

Comment: If the contract has `IListViewDataSource` as a parameter, you cannot replace it with a subclass in the implementation

Comment: @user7 then what could I do to enforce every ListView having a method to set the data source, and having different types of data sources?

Comment: You could make use of [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) where the type parameter could be a concrete data source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, to override a method, whether you're dealing with interfaces or classes, the signature must match exactly.  This includes the exact type of parameters in the method.

You can get around this with a generic type parameter.

Your `IListView` interface can have a type parameter to specify which type of parameter that `setDataSource` takes.  You can declare it with an upper bound to restrict what it can be.

```
public interface IListView<T extends IListViewDataSource> {
    void setDataSource(T dataSource);
}
```

Implementing classes (or extending interfaces) can declare what `T` is.

```
public class SimpleListView implements IListView<IListViewDataSource> {
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(IListViewDataSource dataSource) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class ComplexListView implements IListView<IComplexListViewDataSource> {
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(IComplexListViewDataSource dataSource) {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Always use the `@Override` annotation to have the compiler ensure that the method actually overrides or implements the intended method.

Additionally, implementing classes or extending interfaces can declare their own type parameter and apply their own restriction with their own upper bound.

```
public interface IComplexListView<T extends IComplexListViewDataSource> extends IListView<T> {}
```